# python 3.4 multiprocessing does not work with unittest

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.4, python-unittest

I have an unittest which is using multiprocessing.

After upgrading from Python 3.2 to Python 3.4 I get following error.
I can't find a hint, what was changed inside Python and what I have to change, to make my code running.

Thanks in advance.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in _main
    self = pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test_multiproc.py", line 46, in testSmallWorkflow
    p.start()
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Python341_64\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Following a sample code, how I can reproduce the error:

```
import shutil
import traceback
import unittest
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
import os


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setUp(self):
        self.working_dir = os.path.join(os.environ["TEMP"], "Testing")
        os.mkdir(self.working_dir)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def tearDown(self):
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            shutil.rmtree(self.working_dir, ignore_errors=True)
        except OSError as err:
            traceback.print_tb(err)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def info(self, title):
        print(title)
        print('module name:', __name__)
        if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
            print('parent process:', os.getppid())
        print('process id:', os.getpid())
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def f(self, name):
        self.info('function f')
        print('hello', name)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def testSmallWorkflow(self):
        self.info('main line')
        p = Process(target=self.f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
        p.join()
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `unittest.TestCase` class itself is no longer pickleable, and you have to pickle it in order to pickle one of its bound methods (`self.f`). An easy workaround would be to create a separate class for the methods you need to call in the child process:

```
class Tester:
    def info(self, title=None):
        print("title {}".format(title))
        print('module name:', __name__)
        if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
            print('parent process:', os.getppid())
        print('process id:', os.getpid())
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def f(self, name):
        self.info('function f')
        print('hello', name)
    #-------------------------------


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setUp(self):
        self.working_dir = os.path.join(os.environ["TEMP"], "Testing")
        os.mkdir(self.working_dir)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def tearDown(self):
        try:
            time.sleep(5)
            shutil.rmtree(self.working_dir, ignore_errors=True)
        except OSError as err:
            traceback.print_tb(err)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def testSmallWorkflow(self):
        t = Tester()
        self.info('main line')
        p = Process(target=t.f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

Alternatively, you use [`__setstate__`/`__getstate__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getstate__) to remove the object from the `TestCase` that's unpickleable. In this case, it's an internal class called `_Outcome`. We don't care about it in the child, so we can just delete it from the pickled state:

```
class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def setUp(self):
        self.working_dir = os.path.join(os.environ["TEMP"], "Testing")
        os.mkdir(self.working_dir)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def tearDown(self):
        try:
            time.sleep(2)
            shutil.rmtree(self.working_dir, ignore_errors=True)
        except OSError as err:
            traceback.print_tb(err)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def info(self, title=None):
        print("title {}".format(title))
        print('module name:', __name__)
        if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
            print('parent process:', os.getppid())
        print('process id:', os.getpid())
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def f(self, name):
        self.info('function f')
        print('hello', name)
    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    def testSmallWorkflow(self):
        t = Tester()
        self.info('main line')
        p = Process(target=self.f, args=('bob',))
        p.start()
        p.join()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['_outcome']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(self_dict)
```

Comment: thanks for the very useful and quick answer. You said, that unittest.Testcase is _no longer_ pickable. Do you have some more information for me about this and why? Maybe some link, where I can read about this?

Comment: @knumskull I don't know if it was documented anywhere; I just figured it out by looking at the code. The issue is that the `_Outcome` object that `TestCase` uses internally contains a `result` attribute that's a `unittest.runner.TextTestResult` instance. This class is responsible for writing the results of each test to the screen. It contains an references to `_io.TextIoWrapper` objects, which can't be pickled. If I find some time this week I may dig into this to see what exactly changed between 3.2 and 3.4, and maybe provide a patch to make TestCase pickleable again.