# How to execute python subTests in parallel?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-unittest, pathos

Consider the following `unittest.TestCase`, which implements two versions of the same test, the only difference being that one executes the `subTest`s in parallel using `multiprocessing`.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from unittest import TestCase


class TestBehaviour(TestCase):
    def _test_equals(self, val):
        for target_val in [1, 2]:
            with self.subTest(target=target_val, source=val):
                self.assertEqual(val, target_val)

    def test_equality_parallel(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
            pool.map(self._test_equals, [1, 2])
            pool.join()
            pool.close()

    def test_equality(self):
        for val in [1, 2]:
            self._test_equals(val)
```

The serial version, `test_equality`, works as expected and produces the following test failures:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_equality (temp.TestBehaviour) (target=2, source=1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 11, in _test_equals
    self.assertEqual(val, target_val)
AssertionError: 1 != 2

======================================================================
FAIL: test_equality (temp.TestBehaviour) (target=1, source=2)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 11, in _test_equals
    self.assertEqual(val, target_val)
AssertionError: 2 != 1
```

On the other hand, `test_equality_parallel` causes an error as the `TestCase` cannot be pickled:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 15, in test_equality_parallel
    pool.map(self._test_equals, [1, 2])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 768, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
```

Now I know that I could split out `_test_equals` as a standalone function outside the class; however, I would like to keep the behaviour of `subTest` to enable better logging (and subsequent debugging) of test failures.

How can I run the tests in parallel, but keep this `subTest` functionality?

**Update**

I have also attempted this using `pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessingPool` to circumvent the issues with `TestCase` serialization; however, in this case `pool.join()` raises `ValueError: Pool is still running`.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
...
    def test_equality_parallel(self):                                           
        pool = ProcessingPool(processes=4)                                      
        pool.map(self._test_equals, [1, 2])
        pool.join()
```

**Update 2**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25646382/python-3-4-multiprocessing-does-not-work-with-unittest) is definitely relevant. The first solution proposed, creating a second class for the methods to be called from the child process, isn't appropriate as it wouldn't enable the use of `subTest`. The second, removing the unpickleable `_Outcome` object from `TestCase` seems hacky and, given that the child processes are running `subTests`, also looks unsuitable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` (and `dill` and `multiprocess`) author.  You are still seeing a serialization error out of `pathos` across processes.  You could, try serializing across threads.  Thread parallel is probably appropriate for this level of function.

```
import multiprocess.dummy as mp
from unittest import TestCase


class TestBehaviour(TestCase):
    def _test_equals(self, val):
        for target_val in [1, 2]:
            with self.subTest(target=target_val, source=val):
                self.assertEqual(val, target_val)

    def test_equality_parallel(self):
        with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
            pool.map(self._test_equals, [1, 2])
            pool.join()
            pool.close()

    def test_equality(self):
        for val in [1, 2]:
            self._test_equals(val)
```

Which yields:

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_equality (test_equaltiy.TestBehaviour)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
...[snip]...
AssertionError: 1 != 2

======================================================================
FAIL: test_equality_parallel (test_equaltiy.TestBehaviour)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
...[snip]...
AssertionError: 1 != 2

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.108s

FAILED (failures=2)
```

This tells me that you might be able to use a serialization variant from `dill` (i.e. within `dill.settings`) to get around the serialization issue.  See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess/issues/48.

Comment: Since my real use case is heavily CPU-bound, process-based threading is what I wanted to implement. Using `multiprocess.Pool` did the job, pickling the `TestCase` without issue.